# Exclude / Skip / Ignore 2 directories from a commit for the current git commit command

Tags: git, git-commit

I have over 100+ files and directories to commit. But I don't want to commit 2 directories for the time being. How can I **skip** or exclude these directories for this commit?

No, it doesnt belong in a .gitignore as I'm just doing it for this instance.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Make a short list of the files you *do* want to add, add them, and commit.  For instance, start with `git status --short > /tmp/list`, then open `/tmp/list` in your favorite editor.  Replace the `M` in front of each file that you *do* want to add with `git add`.  Delete the entire line for each file that you *don't* want to add.  Then run `sh /tmp/list` to execute all the `git add` commands.  Run `git status` again, without `--short` this time if you prefer, to see what you've got staged.

#### Long

You *don't* exclude them.  You keep them around, you just don't *change* them.  This is easier than it sounds.

In Git, *every commit is a complete snapshot of every file.*  (Well, of every file in that commit.)  The *change* between any commit and its parent is something Git figures out *later*, when you ask it: "what's the difference between the complete snapshot X, and the complete snapshot Y?"  That is:

```
...--X--Y   <-- somebranch
```

Here snapshot X has every file in the form it had as of X, and snapshot Y has every file in the form it had as of Y.  To figure out what *changed*, Git will in effect subtract X from Y.

If you *omit* a series of files in commit Y, the answer to *what changed?* is, or includes: *delete all those files.*

---

The way Git builds *new* commits is using something that people variously call the *index*, the *staging area*, or sometimes the *cache*.  You start by doing a `git checkout`:

```
$ git checkout somebranch
```

This does several things, all more or less simultaneously:

- Puts you "on" that branch, so that `git status` says `on branch somebranch`.
- Fills in your *work-tree*—the directory in which you do all your work—from the *tip commit* of branch `somebranch`.
- Fills in your *index* aka *staging area* from that same commit.<sup>1</sup>

The way that Git knows that you are "on" that branch is that Git attaches the special file `HEAD` to that branch name.  The branch name itself identifies the *tip* commit, e.g., commit `Y` as in the drawing above.  Because `HEAD` is attached to `branchname`, both of these resolve to "commit `Y`" at this point.

Note that at this point, all the files in your `HEAD` commit (commit `Y`) *exactly match* all the files in your index, and those match all the files—well, all the *tracked* files—in your work-tree.  Any *untracked* file in your work-tree is a file that is not in your index (and thus is not in commit `Y` either, since your index matches commit `Y`).

---

<sup>1</sup>Git will allow your index and work-tree to differ from your current commit after `git checkout` in *some* cases, but not always.  See [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452) for details.

---

Now suppose you change some, perhaps even many, files in your work-tree.  What happens to the copies of those files in your index?  The answer is: *nothing happens!*  Those files in your index *still match the current commit `Y`*.

If you have something in one file that you want in a new commit `Z`, you must now `git add` the files from the work-tree into the index.  This overwrites the copy that was in the index, using the one from the work-tree instead.

If you have many things in many files, you must `git add` each of those files, or use some sort of en-masse "add all files" operation.  Each added file gets copied over the existing one, so that the work-tree version is now the version in the index.

When you finally run `git commit`, Git packages up *whatever is in the index right now* and uses that for the new commit `Z`.  The new commit's parent is the current commit `Y`, and as soon the commit is saved, Git updates the current branch name so that it points to the *new* commit `Z` instead of the old commit `Y`.  Your `HEAD` remains attached to the branch name, so now you have:

```
...--X--Y--Z   <-- branchname (HEAD)
```

and your index completely matches your current commit.  Your work-tree is different, just as is allowed in the question linked in footnote 1.

You can now `git add` more files, if you like.  Note that unlike committed files, whatever is in the work-tree is *not* stored anywhere permanent, so before you overwrite whatever you have *not* committed, make sure that's OK to do.

Comment: lol, that's ridiculous amount of steps to just exclude 2 directories from getting commited. what if i did a **git commit -am** ? and then uncommit the 2 directories?

Comment: It's no steps at all. Just *don't* `git add` the files you don't want added. Do not use `git commit -a`: that effectively means `git add -u` (add all that Git knows about) followed by `git commit`.